# PandasのDataFrame(Series)で、Decimal型を含む列を検出する方法

Tags: python, python3, pandas

Decimal型の数値を含むDataFrame(Series)を、matplotlibでグラフ表示したいのですが、
Decimal型そのままのデータではエラーとなり、グラフ表示できないようです。
そこで、float型に変換しグラフ表示したいのですが、それぞれの列がDecimal型であるか判定するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？
pd.Series.dtypeでは、object型と表示されてしまい判断できないようです。
要素まで参照しなければ、分からないものなのでしょうか？

```
import decimal
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        {'aa': 'A0', 'bb': 100.1, 'cc': decimal.Decimal('100.1')},
        {'aa': 'A1', 'bb': 200.2, 'cc': decimal.Decimal('200.2')},
        {'aa': 'A2', 'bb': 250.9, 'cc': decimal.Decimal('250.9')},
    ],
    index=[
        pd.Timestamp('2023/04/01', tz='Asia/Tokyo'),
        pd.Timestamp('2023/04/02', tz='Asia/Tokyo'),
        pd.Timestamp('2023/04/03', tz='Asia/Tokyo'),
    ]
)

df.info()
display(df)
print(f"cc列のdtype:[{df['cc'].dtype}]")
# ↑DataFrameもしくはSeriesからでは、object型と表示されてしまうので、
# Decimal型かどうか判定できない？

for item in df['cc']:
    print(type(item), item)
```

↓確認用コードの実行結果です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【追記】
以下のように、Seriesを抽出してplotするとエラーが発生します。
多数の列があり、どの列がどの型か分からなくて、質問しました。

```
import decimal
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        {'aa': 'A0', 'bb': 100.1, 'cc': decimal.Decimal('100.1')},
        {'aa': 'A1', 'bb': 200.2, 'cc': decimal.Decimal('200.2')},
        {'aa': 'A2', 'bb': 250.9, 'cc': decimal.Decimal('250.9')},
    ],
    index=[
        pd.Timestamp('2023/04/01', tz='Asia/Tokyo'),
        pd.Timestamp('2023/04/02', tz='Asia/Tokyo'),
        pd.Timestamp('2023/04/03', tz='Asia/Tokyo'),
    ]
)

# ax = df['bb'].plot()  # ←正しくグラフが書ける
# ax = df['cc'].plot()  # ←エラー（no numeric data to plot）が発生する。
ax = df['cc'].astype(float).plot()  # ←正しくグラフが書ける
```

Comment: 「Decimal型そのままのデータではエラーとなり、グラフ表示できないようです。」とのことですが、どのようなコードを書いてどのようなエラーが発生したのでしょうか？

Comment: df['cc'].plot()とするとエラー（no numeric data to plot）が発生しました。

Comment: 「どの列がどの型か分からなくて」に関しては、`print(df.applymap(type))` を実行して結果を確認してみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Decimal型を含む列

```py
dfx = df.applymap(type).eq(decimal.Decimal)
col = dfx.loc[:, dfx.any()].columns
print(col)

# ['cc']
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。decimal型の列を検出することができました。

Answer (score 0):

変換するだけなら以下のように

```py
df['cc_float'] = df['cc'].astype(float)

df.iloc[1,1] = 207
df.plot()
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

下記のようなコードで型変換するのはどうでしょうか？

```
df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: float(x) if type(x) == decimal.Decimal else x)
print(df2.dtypes)
# aa     object
# bb    float64
# cc    float64
# dtype: object
```

Comment: できました。ありがとうございます。各セルの型を見る必要があること分かりました。
型変換に、だいたい50万件で５秒程かかりました。データ量との兼ね合いをみて盛り込んでいきます。

Answer (score 0):

Decimal型を検出する方法ではないですが、エラーを無視して変換することで、
パフォーマンスの低下をおさえつつ、グラフ表示できるようになりました。
df[col_name] = df[col_name].astype(float, errors='ignore')

```
import decimal
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        {'aa': 'A0', 'bb': 100.1, 'cc': decimal.Decimal('100.1')},
        {'aa': 'A1', 'bb': 200.2, 'cc': decimal.Decimal('200.2')},
        {'aa': 'A2', 'bb': 250.9, 'cc': decimal.Decimal('250.9')},
    ],
    index=[
        pd.Timestamp('2023/04/01', tz='Asia/Tokyo'),
        pd.Timestamp('2023/04/02', tz='Asia/Tokyo'),
        pd.Timestamp('2023/04/03', tz='Asia/Tokyo'),
    ]
)

df.info()
print('')

for col_name in df:
    df[col_name] = df[col_name].astype(float, errors='ignore')
df.info()
```